# Access is denied - HTTP Post

Tags: http, authorization, scadalts

I am new to SCADA LTS and wanted to delve into it more closely. When attempting to create an external connector, I thought that using HTTP would be the simplest option, as it doesn't require any special hardware or software. However, while following the instructions, I encountered an HTTP 403 error, indicating that my input is not authorized.

I attempted to send data to the system using the following POST:
http://localhost:8080/Scada-LTS/httpds?testKey=testValue

I have installed the latest version of SCADA LTS and I am running it on an Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine hosted on a Windows 10 PC.

Any idea how to fix this or why I get this error?

I have already attempted to send a POST from different PCs, directly from the VM and from the host PC or an external PC. I was logged into the system from all of them. However, I received the same 403 error with all of them.

Comment: Please [edit] and **quote complete error text**. problem's often in the nitty-gritty...